# How can I make an text hyperlink to a picture in a LaTeX document?

Tags: graphics, hyperref, links

## Problem no 1 :

I want to try making a text hyperlink . If I click this link , this will redirect to a picture within the pdf of latex .

## My endeavors :

I have tried the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx}    
\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{general_view_of_mcc.png}
      \caption{General view of MCC}
      \label{fig:boat1}
    \end{figure}        
    Figure \ref{fig:boat1} shows a boat.
\end{document}
```

Now I want to click in the text "fig:boat1" and want to go in the image named general_view_of_mcc.png .

## Problem no 2 :

I want to try making a text hyperlink . If I click this link , this will redirect to a item of bibliography within the pdf of latex .

How can I solve this two problems ? I have searched a lot in the internet but could not find any helpful link . Please help me in this matter .

Comment: It will be easier and more joyful to help you if you provide some minimal (non)working example of code, with what you have tried so far.

Comment: 1: You need the `hyperref` package ... label your figures with  \label{name} -> and use \ref{label} in the text 2: `biblatex` will help see [Minimal working example with Bibliography((for BibLaTeX)))?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/124842)

Comment: My question is updated . Hope this will let you understand about my endavors .

Comment: Minimal example means: It starts with `\documentclass{...` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can use `example-image` instead of `general_view_of_mcc.png`. In this way everyone can compile and test the code without having the picture.

Comment: The code is updated with minimal example . Please see this .

Comment: As for the link to the figure, your example should perfectly work.

Comment: No I cant click in the text "fig:boat1 " . I have no idea why .

Comment: @campa Not working for me.

Comment: @IccheGuri What is your PDF reader ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your example is working, but with the link not coloured and very close to the image, it's very hard to see the effect of `hyperref`. Try this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[%  
    colorlinks=true,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    linkcolor=red
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
       \rule{4cm}{4cm}
%      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{general_view_of_mcc.png}                                                      
      \caption{General view of MCC}
      \label{fig:boat1}
    \end{figure}
abc
\newpage
    Figure \ref{fig:boat1} shows a boat.
\end{document}
```

The number `1` on the second page should be red, and clicking it should take you back to the first page.